# Project Euler #3

Tags: java

**Question:**

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

I found this one pretty easy, but running the file took an extremely long time, it's been going on for a while and the highest number I've got to is 716151937.

Here is my code, am I just going to have a wait or is there an error in my code?

```
        //User made class
public class Three
{   
        public static boolean checkPrime(long p)
        {
            long i;
            boolean prime = false;
        for(i = 2;i<p/2;i++)
        {
            if(p%i==0)
            {
                prime = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    return prime;
    }
```

}

```
    //Note: This is a separate file
public class ThreeMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            long comp = 600851475143L;
            boolean prime;
            long i;
            for(i=2;i<comp/2;i++)
            {
                if(comp%i==0)
                {
                    prime = Three.checkPrime(i);
                    if(prime==true)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
}
```

Comment: You only have to loop to `sqrt(n)`, not `n/2`. Also, you can check the 2 case, then start at 3 and increment by 2 each time to double the speed. Also, `== true` is pointless. Also also, it is not evil to have multiple exit points to a function, so you can just `return false;`. Also also also note that it's `false`, not `true` - if the number is divisible by `i`, it's *composite*.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're running a separate loop to check if the factors are prime? That's *really* slow. Just keep dividing the number to get its prime factors.

Comment: [Like so.](http://ideone.com/8OAGfD) Or, since it's obviously not divisible by 2, [shave another 0.02 seconds off](http://ideone.com/ITjWcD).

Answer (score 1):

You're headed in the right direction, but you've gone way past where you need to go and have a couple of mistakes along the way. You're currently checking much higher than you need to verify primes (particularly primes >> 2).
Your line: `for(i = 2;i<p/2;i++)` could be `for(i = 2;i*i <= p;i++)` (you need only check up to the square root of a number to determine if it's prime or composite).

Your function to check for primes actually returns true for composites, not primes. You're code:

```
    if ((p%i==0) {
        prime = true;
        break; }
```

should be

```
    if ((p%i==0) {
        prime = false;
        break; }
```

In your main method, you don't actually need the `boolean prime` at all. From the context of the question, we can assume that there will be more than two prime factors, which means the largest prime factor we need to reduce comp to a smaller and more manageable number is the cube root of comp. Therefore, your line `for(i=2;i<comp/2;i++)` could be `for(i=2;i*i*i<comp;i++)`. Instead of continually checking if `i`  divides `comp` and then checking if `i` is prime, you can reduce the size of `comp` by dividing by `i` until `comp` is not divisible by `i` anymore (to check for powers of `i`). Because you're starting with small values of `i` then you will never get a composite number that divides `comp` if you reduce it by `i` each time. When you've reduced `comp` to 1 then the current `i` will be the greatest prime factor and your answer to the problem.

Also, you're lines:

```
    prime = Three.checkPrime(i);
    if(prime==true)
```

can be reduced to:

```
if (Three.checkPrime(i));
```

because Three.checkPrime() will return, and ultimately be evaluated as, a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop to `sqrt(2)` instead of `n/2` which will save lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've found a factor of your number, you can divide it out to make the remaining number smaller.

```
if (prime)
{
    System.out.println(i);

    // The factor may occur multiple times, so we need a loop.                
    do {
        comp /= i;
    } while (comp % i == 0);
}
```

Doing this also guarantees that whenever `i` divides `comp`, `i` must be prime since all the smaller primes have already been divided out, so you can remove the prime check:

```
for (i = 2; i < comp/2; i++)
{
    if (comp % i == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(i);

        do {
            comp /= i;
        } while (comp % i == 0);
    }
}
```

Finally, you only need to check `i` up to the square root of `comp` since any factor larger than the square root must be accompanied by one that's smaller than the square root. (i.e. if `i*j == comp`, one of `i` or `j` must be `<=` the square root of `comp`).

There are a few more tricks that can be applied, but this should be more than enough for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is slow. Here's the standard way to factor an integer by trial division:

```
define factors(n)
    f = 2
    while f * f <= n
        if n % f == 0
            output f
            n /= f
        else
            f = f + 1
    output n
```

There are better ways to factor integers; you can read about some of them in an essay at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays). But this algorithm is sufficient for Project Euler #3, delivering an answer in less than a second in most any modern language.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am writing two different logic to solne this problem  . I am quite sure it work faster

**First one is**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Problem3 {
public void hfactor(long num)
 {
  List<Long> ob =new ArrayList<Long>();
 long working =num;
  long current =2;
  while(working !=1)
   {boolean isprime = true;
    for(Long prime :ob)
    {
      if(current%prime == 0)
       { isprime =false;
         break;   
       }
    }
    if(isprime)
    {ob.add(current);
       if(working%current ==0)
       {
       working /=current;
        }
     } 

  current++;    
    }
    System.out.println(ob.get(ob.size()-1));
   }    


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Problem3 ob1 =new Problem3();
  ob1.hfactor(13195);
  }
  }
```

**Second is**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <Long> ob = new ArrayList<Long>(); 
    List<Long> ob1 = new ArrayList<Long>();

    long num =13195;
    for(int i = 2; i<num; i++)
      {
       if (num%i ==0)
         ob.add((long) i);  
      }

    for (int i =0; i<ob.size(); i++)
        for(int j =2; j<ob.get(i); j++)
            {
             if (ob.get(i)%j ==0)
                {
                 ob.set(i, (long) 0);
                    }
             }
           for(int i =0; i<ob.size(); i++){
              if(ob.get(i)!=0)
              {
                 ob1.add(ob.get(i)); 
              } 


             }

        System.out.println(ob1.get(ob1.size()-1));



    }}
```